# Python: error with random.choice after compiling with py2exe

Tags: python, random, compilation, py2exe

I have a Python program that runs correctly in Python, but errors occur after compiling it with `py2exe`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "annotate.py", line 229, in <module>
  File "random.pyc", line 274, in choice
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Line 229, in which the error occurs, is the following:

```
file = random.choice(filenames)
```

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and py2exe 0.6.9 for Python 2.7.
The program to compile the program with, was the following (and it was in the tutorial on the py2exe website):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['annotate.py'])
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.choice()` throws an `IndexError` because `filenames` is empty:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You'll need to figure out why `filenames` is empty when running under `py2exe`. Perhaps you are counting on filesystem access to python files that `py2exe` has zipped up into an archive for distribution?

Comment: That's it, thanks! Because `py2exe` makes a new folder, the filepath to collect `filenames` from was different, so there were no filenames collected and `filenames` was empty. I just had to add "\\.." to the filepath.